# Sum of bitwise OR of all subarrays of an array using java

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation

You are given an array of integers A of size N.

The value of a subarray is defined as BITWISE OR of all elements in it.

Return the sum of value of all subarrays of A % 10^9 + 7.

```
public class Solution {
    public int solve(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        long M = 1000000007;

        int N = A.size();
        
        long totalSubarrays = (N*(N+1))/2;
        long totalORSum = 0; //sum of bitwise OR of all subarrays
        
        //step1: traverse through each bit of element of array
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            long subArrayUnsetBit = 0;
            long zeroCount = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                //2.check if bit is unset(0).count the number of unset bits.
                //Calculate the number of sub arrays with unset ith bit position

                //for each element, check if bit at "position" is unset
                //if it's unset, add to the total
                //since we are looking for number of subarrays, if there are continuous unset bit position, the number of subarrays will depend on it as well. 
                if ((1 & (A.get(j) >> i)) != 1) {
                    zeroCount++;
                } else {
                    subArrayUnsetBit = subArrayUnsetBit + (zeroCount * (zeroCount + 1)) / 2;
                    zeroCount = 0;//reset
                }

            }
            //get the number of subarrays which have ith bit as unset
            subArrayUnsetBit = subArrayUnsetBit + (zeroCount*(zeroCount+1))/2;
            //number of sub arrays which have ith bit set
            long subArraySetBit = totalSubarrays - subArrayUnsetBit;
            //if ith bit is set, its value would be: 2^i == (1<<i)
            long powerValue = (1<<i);
            //contribution to total sum by all subarrays which has set bit at ith position
            long contribution = (subArraySetBit * powerValue);
            totalORSum = (totalORSum + contribution);

        }
        return (int)(totalORSum % M);
        
    }
}
```

The above code is working perfectly fine for small size arrays ex:[1,2,3,4,5] answer = 71.
But failing for large test cases.
[image]

Please help with what I'm missing?

Comment: `sum % (10^9 + 7)` (code) or `(sum % 10^9) + 7` (text) ?

Comment: Is it possible to provide the input from the large test case?
It's been a while since I last used bitwise or, but there may be an issue with the data type limits exceeding (overflow) when dealing with large numbers. You are using modulo in the end, I'd probably try to add it for the intermediate results as well to keep the final result in bounds (i.e. for subArrayUnsetBit, subArraySetBit, totalORSum calculations)

Comment: well, lets be a little bit more explicit: in the text you wrote `answer % 10^9 + 7`, which, by *conventional* precedence rules, would correspond to  `(answer % 10^9) + 7`; but in the code you wrote `answer % 1000000007`, that would be `answer % (10^9 + 7)` - so, what should it be? (I did not ask for what that is intended)

Comment: @user85421 it should be this answer % (10^9 + 7) as in code.

Comment: try using **Modular Arithmetic** for all the calculation, as there might be a overflow occuring  for other operations. `(a + b) mod m = ((a mod m) + (b mod m)) mod m` and `(a × b) mod m = ((a mod m) × (b mod m)) mod m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the array length(N) to long data type. I was able to handle hard test cases efficiently.

```
int N = A.size();
```

to

```
long N = A.size();
```

Comment: This fixes `(N*(N+1))/2` which can otherwise overflow. In general that may not be enough, maybe it is enough with the test cases you got, but I can still imagine cases that are too big if you don't do modulo reductions on some intermediate results.